# Why is this DataGridView cell formatting wrong?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I have some code for the column that looks like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewLinkCell cell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
  cell.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
  cell.VisitedLinkColor = Color.Blue;

  foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView2.Rows)
  {
    r.Cells["url"] = cell;
  }
}
```

I also have some double-clicking code that looks like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView2.Columns[dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.Contains("URL"))
  {
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://" + dataGridView2.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in this column, I double-click on a cell that has the content http://aweber.com. My laptop takes me to my browser but a page comes up saying it is having a problem finding the file.
I look in the address bar of the browser and find http//aweber.com (there's no colon).

Why is the colon removed?

Comment: After numerous tests, I am unable to reproduce what you describe. It is unclear what exactly the cells in the “url” column contain? Is it a mix of text and links or do all the cells contain links? I assume that ALL the cells in the “url” column are supposed to be “links.” This assumption is made from the first snippet of code. Even though the code is invalid and will crash, it appears to be setting “each” cell in the “url” column to a `DataGridViewLinkCell`? This is odd, is there some reason you do not use a `DataGridViewLinkColumn`? This would eliminate the code in the binding complete event.

Comment: If you can clarify any of this… it would help. Since I am unable to reproduce what you describe, can you post a “complete” example of code that CAN reproduce what you describe. I have tried different links, browsers etc. And at no time did the “:” character disappear in the address bar. However, I did get a few errors where “www” was added to the string and some other minor things that messed up the link, unfortunately, ALL these problems were coming from the “browser” settings/options. Testing using different browsers may be revealing.

Comment: There isn’t much your code can do once it passes the address string to the browser. And lastly to clarify “why” the code in the first snippet will crash on the line… `r.Cells["url"] = cell;` … is because the grid will not allow the “same” CELL to occupy TWO (2) different cells in the grid. The first iteration of the loop will work; however, it will crash on the second iteration with an error stating something like… _Cell provided already belongs to a grid._ The code needs to add “new” cell with each iteration. Again, none of this is necessary if you use a link column.

Comment: To clarify, I have a user enter a URL on a separate screen. When they click on save of that screen, the screen closes and the data source is reset. I want the user to have the option of giving or not giving the protocol prefix of the url. So in the DataBindingComplete event, I want to set the entire URL column as a hyperlink column wheather the content of the cell contains https:// or http:// or not.

Comment: Hmmm. _”So in the DataBindingComplete event, I want to set the entire URL column as a hyperlink column wheather the content of the cell contains https:// or http:// or not.”_ …?  Well Ok. I am not sure how this pertains to my question, but that if fine. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($"{dgv.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue}");
```

Comment: I tried that but it's giving me syntax errors. I tried System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($@"http://"+dataGridView2.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue); That doesn't give me syntax errors but the browser still comes up with http//aweber.com

Comment: Has the cell content  http as well?

Comment: Check the updated answer it should be run without problems if the cell content has the complete url